# How can I use a ::before selector at the bottom of my element?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use my ::before selector on the bottom of my div box (like in the example image. I was wondering if there is something like an ::under selector?

[image]

```css
.direct-chat-text {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #d2d6de;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    margin: 0px 150px 0 50px;
    color: #444444;
}



.direct-chat-text::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 15px;
    border: solid transparent;
        border-top-width: medium;
        border-right-width: medium;
        border-bottom-width: medium;
        border-left-width: medium;
        border-right-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #d2d6de;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="direct-chat-text">3</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.direct-chat-text {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #d2d6de;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    margin: 0px 150px 0 50px;
    color: #444444;
}

.direct-chat-text::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #d2d6de;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="direct-chat-text">3</div>
```

Reference (css shape) : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, change left to right and other improvements

```css
.direct-chat-text {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #d2d6de;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    margin: 0px 150px 0 50px;
    color: #444444;
}



.direct-chat-text::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 100%;
    border-top: 6px solid #d2d6de;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="direct-chat-text">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ::under pseudo element. There is the [::after](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-after). 
But it does not matter in the context of your question. To make [triangle down](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#triangle-down) shape use `border` CSS proberty of any element (or pseudo element). Then postion one. In your case:

```css
.with-under {
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #d2d6de;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    margin: 0px 150px 0 50px;
    color: #444444;
}

.with-under::before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 95%;
    margin-left: -6px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #d2d6de;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-under">3</div>
```